# Golang rpc call resolve unexpected EOF

Tags: go, tcp, rpc, tcpclient

I am getting an unexpected EOF error after the execution of Call function in client code.I have a tcp server listening on port 8081 and have defined custom format for RPC request and response type.

**Client Code**

```
    c, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Tcp Connection Error")
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    response := new(Result)
    err = c.Call("Profile.Manage", msg, response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

**Server Code**

```
    handleobj := login_change.NewProfile()
    rpc.Register(handleobj)
    PORT := "127.0.0.1:8081"
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", PORT)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
    }
    defer l.Close()
    rpc.Accept(l)
```

**Common Package**

```
type Profile struct{}

func (h *Profile) Manage(b Msgobject, res *Result) (err error) {
    res.Message = "Control reached"
    return nil
}

func NewProfile() *Profile {
    return &Profile{}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved now,I was actually trying to perform operations on a variable which was initialized by a different process thus resulting in this issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: @mcjcloud Don't remember much now, but as the answer reads, the inter process communication was established incorrectly. It was trying to read variable which was initialized by other process thus essentially in a separate memory space.